# Model only opens if I refresh the page manually

Tags: angular

When the user clicks on the email verification link from his email then he is taken to mywebsite.com/?token=tokenstringexample
If the token is correct then  `this.token = true;` is set to true and if its true then the model should show.
I printed the value of token in the template and console and there is no problem there its updating printing the correct value but the model doesnt show when the user clicks the link from his email, but if I set the value of token = true in the .ts file or set the value of token==undefined in the html and then refresh the page then the model shows. I wonder if its is due to response time, the page is loading but the response comes later which sets it to true.

```
<div *ngIf="token==true">
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Congrats!<br> Your Account is now active</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>You may now login</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Typescript

```
declare var $: any;

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
token: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
this.chk.activateUser(token).subscribe( (res) => {
      if(res) {
        this.token = true;
        console.log(this.token);
        ............
        ............
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    }
```

Comment: *ngIf="token==true" can just be *ngIf="token"

Answer (score 0):

You can directly show the modal using `$('#myModal').modal('show');` without using  `$(document).ready` function.Remove the `*ngIf` property because the changeDetection happens only if all the lines gets executed

- The `ready()` method is used to make a function available after the
  document is loaded

Comment: You should remove the ngIf property

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ngIf and JQuery hide/show methods at the same time? It's bad practice to use JQuery with the newer angular. Try just using a *ngIf with the token member.